# Chatfuel: Creating two different chatbots that are connected to two different facebook pages

Tags: chat, bots, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, chatfuel

is it possible with the same chatfuel account to build two different chatbots that are connected with two different facebook pages? I want chatbot A to be connected with facebook page A, and I want chatbot B to be connected with facebook page B but I want to build them with the same chatfuel account.
If it´s possible how do I do it?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that. As you can get many facebook page you can have many chatfuel bots connected to them.